# Why is scrolling in NavigationView dependent on outside xml elements?

Tags: android, xml, scroll, navigationview

I'm placing a table of contents menu inside a right-sided NavigationView.  Here is my code that works:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/top_nav_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The main content gets loaded in here. -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/grandparent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="my.Activity">

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/toc_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/burger_menu_header"
        app:theme="@style/TableOfContents_TextAppearance"
        app:menu="@menu/burger_menu_drawer_items"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In a previous version of the code, I had the NavigationView above the main content-holding LinearLayout.  Like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/top_nav_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/toc_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/burger_menu_header"
        app:theme="@style/TableOfContents_TextAppearance"
        app:menu="@menu/burger_menu_drawer_items"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <!-- The main content gets loaded in here. -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/grandparent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="my.Activity">

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In that version, the system (both on an emulator and hardware test device) displayed the right-sided drawer, and displayed the first few elements of the menu, but I could not scroll to the bottom of the menu.  The scroll bar would appear if I turned it on manually in the xml code, but it just didn't know there was any content beyond the immediately visible.

My question is why?  What is the drawing logic behind the scenes that makes the scrolling magic work?

For completeness, burger_menu_header.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/toc_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Table of Contents"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and burger_menu_drawer_items.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_0"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Introduction"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 1 - The Adventure"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 2 - Our Heroes Go Sailing"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 3 - The Ship Is LostAtSeaFarAway"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 4 - Skipper Wins!"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_5"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 5"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_6"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 6"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_7"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 7"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_8"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 8"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_9"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 9"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_10"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 10"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_11"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 11 - No Way Is This Happening, She Cried"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_12"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 12 - The End?"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_13"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 13 - But Wait..."/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_14"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 14 - But Wait..."/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_chapter_15"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_black_24dp"
        android:title="Chapter 14 - Nah, It Was Nothing"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Drawer `View`s in a `DrawerLayout` must be listed after the main content `View` to ensure correct z-ordering. In your second example, the drawer is ending up "under" the main content, which will get first chance to handle touch events. I would also mention that you should have only one non-drawer `View`; i.e., your `AppBarLayout` and the main content should all be in one `ViewGroup`, however you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks Mike M.!  Your answer came through as a comment, and I'm not being given an "accept as answer" button.  If you re-post, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Actually, I've answered this a few times previously, in one form or another. I'll just mark this question as a duplicate. Thanks, though. Appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Comment: you can check here for complete solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/51452908/2788786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about

> Z-Index

Gothamgreen.

```
<item num1
<item num2 is above 1
<item num3 is above 2
```

> So it is important that the item that needs touch or focus gets the
>   touch or focus. This is determined first by z-index. In the example
>   above item 3 has the greatest z-index and gets first attempt at
>   handling the touch before it is passed to item 2 and then if item 2
>   doesn't handle the touch it will go to item 1.

So imagine you had

```
<content>
<drawerNav>
```

drawerNav gets first attempt to handle touch and will open/close etc. on touch or swipe. if not needing to handle it will pass through to content view.

now let's consider

```
<drawerNav>
<content>
```

content is full screen and will consume touch everytime and never pass through to the drawer, so the drawer will only work from the hamburger menu and not the swipe, and even that is iffy.

So as you can see it has to do with touch handling order via zindex.

Comment: Thanks Sam and Mike.  Follow-up question.  If the z-index stack is wrong, why am I still seeing the drawer contents?  Why is z-index applying to touch events, but not display allocation?

Comment: Well if i had to take a guess, I would assume the style applied to navigationDrawer is that of a floating style that causes it to come to front in terms drawing, but not reprioritizing the zindex for touch. However, I am not positive on that.